# upgrade gcc + compiling ROOT

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu-14.04, root-framework

I am working on ROOT v6.06.06 on ubuntu 14.04. Everything went OK.
Lately i did apt-get upgrade, and this affected the c++ compiler.

Since then, when i try to run my macros on ROOT, I have this error:
`fatal error: file '/usr/include/c++/4.9/cmath' modified since it was first processed`

I tried then to re-compile ROOT, but it's not working, I have this error:
`[ 36%] Building CXX object interpreter/llvm/src/tools/clang/lib/Driver/CMakeFiles/clangDriver.dir/ToolChains.cpp.o
.../root/interpreter/llvm/src/tools/clang/lib/Driver/ToolChains.cpp: In static member function ‘static std::string clang::driver::toolchains::Hexagon_TC::GetGnuDir(const string&, const llvm::opt::ArgList&)’:
.../root/root6/root/interpreter/llvm/src/tools/clang/lib/Driver/ToolChains.cpp:2110:42: error: ‘LLVM_PREFIX’ was not declared in this scope
   std::string PrefixRelDir = std::string(LLVM_PREFIX) + "/../gnu";
                                          ^
make[2]: *** [interpreter/llvm/src/tools/clang/lib/Driver/CMakeFiles/clangDriver.dir/ToolChains.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [interpreter/llvm/src/tools/clang/lib/Driver/CMakeFiles/clangDriver.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2`

So I need either solving the c++ compiler so i can use the last compiled version of ROOT that I have,
Or succeed to solve the problem while compiling ROOT.

Can you help me please? I am blocked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well.. I have researched bit... but can't find much reference but hope it helps: https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=21027 and https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=22202

Comment: @Sean83 Thanks for help, 
I added this to **interpreter/llvm/src/include/llvm/Config/llvm-config.h** the following:
`#define LLVM_PREFIX "/usr/local"`
and then I recompiled ROOT from scratch.
Now everything is working fine.